# Question about calculating confidence intervals

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, random-variable

I am reading about confidence intervals and got stuck with this example from L. Wasserman's book titled "All of Statistics". Could anybody explain why P<sub>Q</sub>(θ ∈ C) = 3/4 in this example? Below is the paragraph from the book:

> Let θ be a fixed, known real number and let X<sub>1</sub>,
>   X<sub>2</sub> be independent random variables such that
>   P(X<sub>i</sub> = 1) = P(X<sub>i</sub> = -1) = 1/2. Now define
>   Y<sub>i</sub> = θ + X<sub>i</sub> and suppose that you only observe
>   Y<sub>1</sub> and Y<sub>2</sub>. Define the following interval that
>   actually contains only one point:

[image]

> You can check that, no matter what θ is, we have P<sub>θ</sub>(θ ∈ C)
>   = 3/4 so this is a 75 percent confidence interval. Suppose we now do the experiment and we get Y<sub>1</sub> = 15 and Y<sub>2</sub> = 17.
>   Then our 75 percent confidence interval is {16}. However, we are
>   certain that θ = 16. If you wanted to make a probability statement
>   about θ you would probably say that P(θ ∈ C|Y<sub>1</sub>,
>   Y<sub>2</sub>) = 1. There is nothing wrong with saying that {16} is a
>   75 percent confidence interval. But is it not a probability statement
>   about θ.

Comment: I didn't fing the definition of $\theta$, is it the same as Q ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Sorry for that. I'll change. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: There are only four possible outcomes: make a four-row table of the possibilities, work out their probabilities, and check which rows correspond to the event ${\Pr}_\theta(\theta\in C).$

Comment: @whuber sorry, can you elaborate on that?. I only see that X1 and X2 can be 1 or -1 and in both cases they have P = 1/2. They are independent, thus P(X,Y) for all 4 possibilities is 1/4. How then we get 3/4 for Q?

Comment: Because the event comprises three of the rows, whence its chance is three times 1/4.

Comment: sorry for silly questions, don't get it. Why three rows? When Q is not in C? @whuber

Comment: Oh, is that because when Y1 does not equal Y2 the Y1 or Y2 (one of them) is not within C because of averaging? Other times, all Ys are within C? Thus, we get 3/4? @whuber

Comment: All you need to do is apply the formula for $C$ to each row and check whether $\theta=C.$

Comment: Got it, thanks! @whuber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dissociate cases :

- if $X_1 \neq X_2$, which happens with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, then $X_1 = -X_2$ (since $X$ can only be $1$ or $-1$) and $Y_1 \neq Y_2$. So $C = \{\frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{2}\} = \{\theta\}$. So $\theta \in C$.
- if $X_1 = X_2 = 1$, which happens with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, then $Y_1 = Y_2 = \theta + 1$ and $C = \{\theta\}$. So $\theta \in C$.
- if $X_1 = X_2 = -1$, which happens with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, then $Y_1 = Y_2 = \theta - 1$, and $C = \{\theta - 2\}$. So $\theta \notin C$.

So the only possible case in which $\theta \notin C$ is when $X_1 = X_2 = -1$, which happens with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, so $P(\theta \in C) = 1 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$

I think the point of Wasserman here is that the randomness lies in $C$ and not $\theta$. And indeed in the different cases considered, each time it is the confidence intervall $C$ which changes, not $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I understood everything